# How to pass event to riemann using different port

Tags: clojure, logstash, riemann

I am trying to load my `Logstash` event to `Riemann`. when I am using the default setup(default port `5555/5556`). Events are getting passed to Riemann without any issues.

When I try to run the Riemann using custom port, the events are not getting passed to Riemann. Below are my config details which I am using,

**Riemann config file:**

```
(tcp-server {:host "127.0.0.1" :port 5552})
```

**Logstash File:**

```
riemann{
            host=> localhost
            port => 5552 
            riemann_event =>  {
                        "service" => "sys_log"                                              
                        "metric" => "%{metric}"
                        "ttl" => "%{ttl}"                       
                      }         
        }
```

I have checked the port also it was up and running but I dont know why the event was not getting triggered to riemann with custom port.

I have checked the riemann logs I got the following message

```
INFO [2016-01-13 06:57:48,307] main - riemann.bin - PID 10423
INFO [2016-01-13 06:57:48,606] clojure-agent-send-off-pool-2 - riemann.transport.tcp - TCP server 127.0.0.1 5552 online
INFO [2016-01-13 06:57:48,607] main - riemann.core - Hyperspace core online
```

The following config was working fine

**Riemann config file:**

```
(let [host "127.0.0.1"]
  (tcp-server {:host host})
  (udp-server {:host host})
  (ws-server  {:host host}))
```

**Logstash File:**

```
riemann{
            host=> localhost
            riemann_event =>  {
                        "service" => "sys_log"                                              
                        "metric" => "%{metric}"
                        "ttl" => "%{ttl}"                       
                      }         
        }
```

I don't if I am missing any additional setting.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The above setup just working fine now. I have restarted my server and Riemann server, after that events are started flowing into Riemann from Logstash without any issues.

I hope it might help someone, who is trying to use custom port for Riemann